# Cannot find and delete erroneous Blender Add On

Tags: add-on

I once installed an incompatible addon. Now I'm getting error message but unable to locate the said addon and hence uninstall it. (addon name is SetOriginToBottom.py)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I solved my problem just after posting. Here's what I did. I opened the console and checked the location of the bad addon and simply deleted it from that location and !voila! the error message is gone!